# Lottie file not animated in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, lottie, lottie-react-native

I'm using React Native with TypeScript and Expo. I downloaded a JSON file of an animated icon from Lottie Files, but it's not animating. I'm not sure what I'm missing; I followed the documentation.

this is my Imports

```
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
```

useRef

```
 const animationRef = useRef<LottieView>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    animationRef.current?.play();

    
  }, []);
```

component

```
 <LottieView
            style={styles.lottie}
            ref={animationRef}
            source={require("../assets/animated_icon.json")}
          />
```